# Google Search Console API: How do I Solve "User does not have sufficient permission for site"? (When User Has Permissions)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-search-console, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to use Google's Search Console API via their Node package, and my code looks like the following:

```
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
});
const webmasters = google.webmasters('v3');
const params = {
  auth,
  siteUrl: 'example.com',
  resource: {
    startDate: '2015-08-25',
    endDate: '2015-08-25',
    dimensions: ['query', 'page'],
    rowLimit: 10,
  },
  aggregationType: 'byPage',
};
const res = await webmasters.searchanalytics.query(params);
console.log(res.data);
```

... except that in my version `example.com` has been replaced with my actual domain.

I'm invoking it at the command line with:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/service_key.json" node index.js
```

I have a service account created, and the service key JSON file is from it.  That service account has access to my Search Console account.  When I look at https://search.google.com/search-console/users I see the service user there, and in the Permission column it has "Full".

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting the following error when I run my code?

```
{
  message: "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://example.com'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.",
  domain: 'global',
  reason: 'forbidden'
}
```

The URL mentioned, https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999, simply links me to the search console users page ... which (again) says the service user has full permissions.

Comment: have you found solution @machineghost ? please share if do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After rooting in google forums and rest of internet I have figured out why it happen.

1. Need to copy Service account email, long weird format(example: whiskey-tango-foxtrot@certain-something-0123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com) from Google Cloud: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials to Search Console https://search.google.com/u/1/search-console/users, as a "Full site" user.
2. Make sure you have added that site(as from on Search Console) via your API or with this tool: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/sites/add
3. Then, when you perform "list_sites" request, your site should be listed ere and `permission_level` is "siteFullUser"(according to step 1)
4. When you `add_site` or perform `query` API requests, make sure to set `siteUrl` according to steps above, eg: `http://www.example.com/` (for a URL-prefix property) or `sc-domain:example.com` (for a Domain property)
   Happy coding

Comment: How we can access client's GSC data after OAuth Login?

Comment: Thanks! 1. and 2. seemed essential but I cannot remember having read that anywhere in their docs :/ Maybe Google should rather add a link to this SO answer inside of the error response.